# Destructuring records into custom variable names

Tags: elm

Consider this function:

```
mix : Color -> Color -> Color
mix c1 c2 =
    let 
        { red, green, blue, alpha } = toRgb c1
        { red, green, blue, alpha } = toRgb c2
    in
        ...
```

The above won't work because it's introducing duplicate variable names. **Is it possible to destructure the above values into `r1`, `r2`, `g1`, `g2`, etc?**

For clarification, `toRgb` has this signature:

```
toRgb : Color -> { red:Int, green:Int, blue:Int, alpha:Float }
```

A hypothetical syntax might express better what I'd like to do:

```
mix : Color -> Color -> Color
mix c1 c2 =
    let 
        { red as r1, green as g1, blue as b1, alpha as a1 } = toRgb c1
        { red as r2, green as g2, blue as b2, alpha as a2 } = toRgb c2
    in
        ...
```

Comment: Your proposed solution should work... have you tried it?

Comment: Maybe I posed the question poorly but no, this will not compile.  It will fail with, for example: `There are multiple values named "alpha" in this let-expression.`

What I'm trying to do is destructure the values of each record into their own distinct name.

Comment: By "proposed solution", I meant using `g1`, `g2`, etc.

Comment: I'm destructuring a record, not a tuple.  It doesn't match on position, it matches on name.  Maybe what I'd like to do would be better expressed as a hypothetical syntax: `let { r1 = red, g1 = green, b1 = blue, a1 = alpha } = toRgb c1 ...`

Comment: [From what I can gather](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-compiler/issues/366#issuecomment-29363712), that's not possible. Seems like the most straightforward solution would be to assign names to the records you're getting back from `toRgb` and then use dot accessors to access the values in the body of your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had trouble figuring out if this was possible and realized that field accessors are so powerful that it didn't matter.

Presumably your code might look something like:

```
mix : Color -> Color -> Color
mix c1 c2 =
  { red   = avg c1.red   c2.red
  , green = avg c1.green c2.green
  , blue  = avg c1.blue  c2.blue
  , alpha = avg c1.alpha c2.alpha
  }
```

Not so terrible or unreadable. BUT, you could even do something like:

```
mix : Color -> Color -> Color
mix c1 c2 =
  { red   = avg .red   c1 c2
  , green = avg .green c1 c2
  , blue  = avg .blue  c1 c2
  , alpha = avg .alpha c1 c2
  }
```

Are those *worse* than:

```
mix : Color -> Color -> Color
mix c1 c2 =
  let
    { red1, green1, blue1, alpha1 } = toRgb c1
    { red2, green2, blue2, alpha2 } = toRgb c2
  in
  { red   = avg red1   red2
  , green = avg green1 green2
  , blue  = avg blue1  blue2
  , alpha = avg alpha1 alpha2
  }
```

Comment: This looks like a nice solution.  You would still need a let statement converting input `Color`s to records.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**
I did not realize `Color` is part of `Core`, so I edit.

You can destruct `Record` with property names.
In case of having multiple values, then you have to have some helper.
Following example, I defined `toTuple` to do that.

```elm
import Color exposing (Color)

toTuple {red, green, blue, alpha}
  = (red, green, blue, alpha)

mix : Color -> Color -> Color
mix c1 c2 =
  let
    (r1, g1, b1, a1) = toTuple <| Color.toRgb c1
    (r2, g2, b2, a2) = toTuple <| Color.toRgb c2
  in
    Color.rgba
      (avg r1 r2)
      (avg g1 g2)
      (avg b1 b2)
      (avgf a1 a2)

avg i j = (i + j) // 2
avgf p q = 0.5 * (p + q)
```

**Original:**

I'm not sure this is what you are looking for but, you do not need to convert it to record.
`case of` allows you to pattern match via constructor function. e.g.

```
type Color = RGB Int Int Int
purple = RGB 255 0 255
printRedVal =
  case purple of
    RGB r g b -> text (toString r)
```

Comment: `Color` is not an arbitrary type and `toRgb` is not an arbitrary function--they are from the core library and the only way to access rgba channels is to convert it to a record.